# Big O and runtime helop

Tags: big-o

[image: .]

I don't know where to start even though O() is given. I need help finding the summation and the runtime and how to obtain an expression for T(n) or T(n,m).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a for loop with one operation in it. Since this operation prints always the same text, it always takes the same time, or in other words "constant time" or O(1). The for loop calls this n times, so this code snippet has the complexity O(n).

If you want so write it as a sum, you can write

> Σ<sub>k=1,...,n</sub>O(1) = n⋅O(1) = O(n)

You could also write it as

> T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)
>   T(1) = O(1)

If you expand this you get the sum above.

Notice: There are a lot of [big-o](/questions/tagged/big-o) questions on stackoverflow about complexity of for loops anf many different kinds. If you do some research, you will find many examples and information to learn more about time-complexity.